# Weird outline around brush strokes in texture paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm trying out the texture layers in texture paint. I've got my base texture and then a completely transparent layer which I want to paint on. I can paint on the base layer no problem, but when I switch to the alpha layer the strokes have a weird black outline around them. Anyone know what's going on?

[image: texture paint problem]

Comment: mind uploading your .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend/ and posting the link here?

Comment: how do I go about that? do I have to pack my textures? never done it before sorry

Comment: no problem. Yep, you should just be able to `External Data > Pack All into .blend`, you might have to have all the objects selected. I am not sure. Then you should just be able to upload it.

Comment: I'm having trouble packing the file, it seems to be looking for an image that's no longer part of the blend. I only have one object with one material, with two textures attached. Soon as I figure it out I'll upload it.

Comment: Did you double check and make sure the images are saved to the hard drive and not just in Blender? This might be the issue, otherwise, just upload the .blend and the two images separately. The images can go here http://www.pasteall.org/pic/

Comment: Okay, think I've done it, url is http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32830 I added a password, but not sure what it does lol. I'll message it to you.

Comment: @Lois Hi, could you explain what was the problem and how you solved it? Since this is a Q&A site, it would help others facing the same issue to find a solution.

Comment: I found the problem, I think. The outline is caused by the `Mix` mode not being exact enough by the looks of it. The alpha mask is spilling over or something. I created a new texture and made its resolution higher like 2048*2048 or even 4096*4096. This took care of the problem for me.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply, Blending Jake solved the problem for me. I increased the size of my alpha layer to 4096x4096 and the outline disappeared. Thanks so much Jake, I can finally get on with some painting now!

Comment: @BlendingJake i had the same issue and your comment solved it. Could you please post it as the answer for other users who have the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

The outline is caused by the `Mix` node not being exact enough because it is a low resolution, try creating an alpha layer with a resolution like 2048*2048 or 4096*4096, this should fix the problem.